# Folder Permissions Issue in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

In my machine (Windows 7 Ultimate installed): if I have user with name A who is also in administrators role and if I have a folder in D: drive that has been owned by user A and all other users all permissions are denied then when if I reformat C: drive and install Windows 7 ultimate again to C: drive but without touching other partitions of the same machine, create A user with same name again with administrators permission will I be able to use that protected folder in D: drive without needing to take owner ship or doing any changes to permissions dialog box.? (I am asking this because I have lot of folders with same situation. Might need to write script if any changes to permissions needed that way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need to take ownership again. The username is irrelevant. Windows uses something called a Secure ID (or SID) to set permissions.

You can use the `takeown` command in an elevated command prompt that will take ownership of a folder and all its sub-folders, like so ([*source*](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/take-ownership-of-file-or-folder-windows-7-vista/)):

> **Taking ownership of a folder**
>
> Use the following syntax:
>
> `takeown /f <foldername> /r /d y`
>
> Then
>   to assign the Administrators group
>   Full Control Permissions for the
>   folder, use this syntax:
>
> `icacls <foldername> /grant administrators:F /T`
>
> The /T parameter
>   is added so that the operation is
>   carried out through all the
>   sub-directories and files within that
>   folder.

Comment: @randolph-potter yes need to go with script,its logical and good behaviour that same user name creation again does not get permission to folders which might cause some security issues itself