# Images not accessible in localhost using wamp in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wamp

I Installed wamp in windows 7 pro, and copied a joomla live site. Everything seems working well except that it doesn't load the images on the page.

Even when I try to access in directly:

localhost/logo.png

Im getting an 403 Forbidden:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /logo.png on this server.

Solutions I have tried are:

1. Using icacls to grant priviledge 
   [Folder Permissions Issue in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/266289/folder-permissions-issue-in-windows-7?rq=1)
2. manually set the permission by right clicking the image and editing the security.

Comment: Got this working.

Comment: How did you fix this? Feel free to post the solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WAMP server transferring each file to WWW folder after run it on the browser, but when you link to image it does n`t transferred to this folder.**

You have to manually copy images to this folder.

If you setup WAMP server on C-Drive you can find this folder at (C:\wamp\www )

Example : Copy your images folder to

> C:\wamp\www

Add your image to the body of the page like that:

> img src="images/pic.jpg"

Your image location will be:

> `http:// localhost/images/pic.jpg`

it does n`t matter which your site folder have this image or not.